Clarifications on Hoeffding-based hypothesis test
Assume that we would like to test $H_0 : \mu = \mu_0$ vs. $H_1 : \mu\neq \mu_0$ for (fixed) $\mu_0 \in \mathbb R$. Define the statistic $W = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - \mu_0$ , where  the $X_i$-s are i.i.d. random variables  and $0\le X_1 \le 1$ (a.s.). Under $H_0$, we assume that $\mathbb E X_1 = \mu_0$.
For educational purposes, we apply Hoeffding's inequality to derive the test threshold, which yields a test of level $\alpha$ for the threshold $c_\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{\log 2/\alpha}{2n}}$, that is,
for this choice of $c_\alpha$, we have that
$$P_{H_0}(|W|>c_\alpha)\le \alpha.$$
So far, everything is clear. Now, to derive the type II error, we compute $$P_{H_1}(|W|<c_\alpha),$$i.e., the probability that $H_1$ holds but we fail to reject $H_0$. Let $\mu_*:=\mu \neq \mu_0$. It seems to be common to assume that $|\mu_*-\mu_0|/2 > c_\alpha$, allowing us to derive $$\begin{align}
P_{H_1}(|W|<c_\alpha) &=P_{H_1}(|W-\mu_*+\mu_*|<c_\alpha) \\
&= P_{H_1}\left(\left|\left(\frac1n\sum_{i}X_i-\mu_*\right)-(\mu_0-\mu_*)\right|<c_\alpha\right)\\
&\le P_{H_1}\left(\left|\left|\frac1n\sum_{i}X_i-\mu_*\right|-|\mu_0-\mu_*|\right|<c_\alpha\right)\\
&= P_{H_1}\left(\left||\mu_0-\mu_*|-\left|\frac1n\sum_{i}X_i-\mu_*\right|\right|<c_\alpha\right) \\
&\le P_{H_1}\left(|\mu_0-\mu_*|-\left|\frac1n\sum_{i}X_i-\mu_*\right|<c_\alpha\right) \\
&\le P_{H_1}\left(2c_\alpha-\left|\frac1n\sum_{i}X_i-\mu_*\right|<c_\alpha\right) \\
&= P_{H_1}\left(\left|\frac1n\sum_{i}X_i-\mu_*\right|>c_\alpha\right) \le \alpha, \\
\end{align}$$where we used the triangle inequality, the reverse triangle inequality, properties of the norm, and Hoeffding's inequality. The result shows that the type II error is upper bounded by $\alpha$.
My questions are:

Are the derivations correct?
Is there a "direct" approach to obtain the bound on the type II error?
What is the interpretation of the assumption $|\mu_*-\mu_0|/2 > c_\alpha$? From my understanding $c_\alpha$ is "fixed" after we fix a level $\alpha$.
Other tests, e.g., the Wald test, have a power function that depends on $\alpha$ and $\mu_*$. While the power function associated to the above test can be lower bounded by $1-\alpha$, the connection to the choice of $\mu_*$ is unclear to me. In particular, plotting $1-\alpha = 1- 2\exp(-2nc_\alpha^2)$ for $n=100$ as a function of $c_\alpha$ yields the below figure, which seems to be an acceptable lower bound (even though the bound is vacuous for $c_\alpha$ close to zero). Is it correct to interpret the values on the $x$-axis as lower bound for $\mu_*-\mu_0$?


